# Dynamic Programming of Median Location

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic

I am stuck on this problem and was wondering if anyone could help me out:
There are n houses on the x-axis {x_1, x_2,...x_n}, I need to find the location on the x-axis that gives me the smallest sum of distances between the houses and the location.

This is trivial of course, but I also need to be able to do it in O(n) time, and I am stuck on the dynamic algorithm.

Edit: Apparently it did not need to be a DP algorithm, which as I said makes it trivial, sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the responses.

Comment: i don't think your question makes sense...  if you are anywhere on the line (in between the houses) and you add up your distance to all the other houses - then that will be the same number no matter where you are...

Comment: @Randy: That's not true. Consider `{1,3,5}`. By your argument, `2` would solve the problem, but it doesn't (`3` is better).

Comment: yes - thanks this is really a median calculation question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know median finding reasonably well, and I know dynamic programming reasonably well, but I don't know of any median finding algorithms that I could reasonably construe as DP.

If your x's were sorted and you didn't know the median was the answer, I could see computing partial sums from the right and left of a given index as DP-ish sub problems.  The optimal solution then minimizes the sum of the right and left partial sums.

But of course, I strongly dislike problems that say, "Solve X with Y", especially when Y doesn't really fit.  "Solve X, you might want to consider using Y", is a much better form of problem.

Comment: The problem doesn't specifically say solve using DP, but it is strongly implied that that is how they want it solved. I will probably just do it another way. Thanks for reaffirming my thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

Solving the problem amounts to finding the median of {x<sub>i</sub>}.

There are well-known linear-time algorithms for finding the median. See, for example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm).

Comment: Yeah I know that the median is the answer, rather is one possible answer, but I believe I need a dynamic algorithm to solve it in order to get credit, which is where I am blanking.

Comment: @GordonSimpson: you might want to try to set up a simple equation and see if it works. If it doesn't, post it here. You know we love it when folks who ask questions first show their own attempts.

Comment: Is the median really the answer? I would have thought the average was the answer.  Consider {1,2,9}.  The sum of distances from the median is (1-2)+(2-2)+(9-2)=6.  The sum of distances from the average is (1-4)+(2-4)+(9-4)=0. (By definition it always equals zero.)  Perhaps I am seriously misinterpreting the question.

Comment: @emory: I think the misunderstanding is that you need to take absolute values (since the distances are not signed): `|1-4|+|2-4|+|9-4|=10`. On the other hand `|1-2|+|2-2|+|9-2|=8`.